# Change all non-alphanumerics to a +

Tags: java, regex, string, string-formatting, alphanumeric

I'm currently in a bit of a pickle.

I have a text box the user enters an address into, which is then sent as part of a url.

Currently, the solution I have works well with a single word - say "Brighton".
But, if the user wants to add more detail to the query - say, a street address, I run into issues.

> 32 Sydney Street, Brighton, The City of Brighton and Hove BN1 4EP, UK

What would be the best way to change it to - I think a regex would do it, but I've always struggled with them.

> 32+Sydney+Street+Brighton+The+City+of+Brighton+and+Hove+BN1+4EP+UK

I'm currently doing this - which I think is messy, and well, just not good programming.
It'd get even more gross if I add conditionals for '++'

```
String[] strArray = str.split(" ");
int strSize = strArray.length;

// Puts the split array back together, and add a plus between the words
str = "";
for (int i = 0; i < strSize; i++) {
    if (i < (strSize - 1))
        str += strArray[i] + "+";
    else
        str += strArray[i];
}

return str;
```

All the ways I'm thinking of run the risk of having two ++ in a row (which would invalidate the url), or are really 'gross' code.

Thanks for your time

Comment: Just do a regex replace of "not-word character or digit" with "+" - `s/[\W\D]+/+/`.

Comment: There should be a close reason labeled "Gimme teh codez".

Comment: Use the way you are thinking of, then just use a while loop to replace all instances of ++ with +...?

Comment: In the first example, you've dropped the commas. Is that what you want to do? In the second example (in the P.S.) how do you _want_ to fix it?

Comment: Please show what you know about replacing characters in Java. As it is, this is a rather poorly phrased / researched question. Not the standard we like to strive for on this site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ollie, this should do it:

```
try {
    String resultString = subjectString.replaceAll("(?i)[^a-z0-9]+", "+");
} catch (PatternSyntaxException ex) {
    // Syntax error in the regular expression
} catch (IllegalArgumentException ex) {
    // Syntax error in the replacement text (unescaped $ signs?)
} catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException ex) {
    // Non-existent backreference used the replacement text
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that works pretty well :) That gives me the issue with double plus signs (if the user leaves a comma, and a space) - I might have to come up with another regex to turn all +* into +, but it's perfect for now.

Thanks for your time :)

Comment: @Ollie Thanks for your feedback. If you give me an example of the problem strings I can look at it.

Comment: Thanks for your time :) If for example the user enters "32 Sydney Street, Brighton, The City of Brighton and Hove BN1 4EP, UK" (note both the commas, and the spaces) it results in "32+Sydney+Street++Brighton++The+City+of+Brighton+and+Hove+BN1+4EP++UK".

Comment: @Ollie Thanks for explaining. I added a `+` at the end of `[^a-z0-9]+` let me know if this does it for you.

Comment: That's perfect! Thank-you, thank-you, thank-you :) - Have a wonderful day/night :)